# Databricks - How to create a Library with updated maven artifacts

Tags: maven, apache-spark, apache-spark-1.4

We initially created a library in databricks using a maven artifact. We see all the jars are present in library and please note that this maven artifact is ours.

We found few issues with the artifact. Fixed it and updated in maven central repository.

Then we created a library in databricks using the artifact from maven repository. In this library we don't see the changes which is present in updated artifact.

Maven artifacts are present in folder /FileStore/jars/maven/. In this folder old version of my artifact is present. I just tried deleting all the folders present in /FileStore/jars/maven/ and re-created the library. But still my library does not contain new artifacts.

Does databricks has local respository? If yes how can we force update it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently databricks does not have provision to update the library.

Only way is to restart detabricks which they will not do.

See databricks [forum](https://forums.databricks.com/questions/1673/how-to-create-a-library-with-updated-maven-artifac.html) for more details

But databricks has accepted and started this functionality. http://feedback.databricks.com/forums/263785-product-feedback/suggestions/9286104-ability-to-clean-local-maven-repository